# I have created a aspx page where i want to check whether the data exists in gridview or not using javascript but the function is not getting executed

Tags: javascript, c#, gridview

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function itemvalidate()
    {
        var checktext = document.getElementById('txtitemcode').value;
        var griddata = document.getElementById('griditemdetails');

        for (var i = 0; i <= griddata.rows.length; i++)
        {
            var currentrow = griddata.rows[i];
            if (currentrow.cells[0].value == checktext)
            {
                alert('Item code matched');
            }
            else
            {
                alert('Item does not exist in the current SA');
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here's the textbox

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtitemcode" runat="server" onchange="javascript:itemvalidate();"></asp:TextBox>
```

The gridview from where i have to check the itemcode

```
         <asp:GridView ID="griditemdetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
             <Columns>
                      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="No.">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                      </asp:TemplateField>
                 <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Item Code" DataField="ProductCode"/>
                 <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="ProductDesc"/>
                 <asp:BoundField HeaderText="UPC" DataField="UBSCode"/>
                 <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Quantity" DataField="qty"/>
                 <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Scanned Quantity" />
                 <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Balanced Quantity" />
                 <asp:CommandField SelectText="View" ShowSelectButton="True" />

             </Columns>
         </asp:GridView>
```

I've binded the gridview data from code behind and now based on the itemcode column i need to validate whether the data entered in the textbox exists in gridview or not

Here's the image of gridview and data inside it 
[Gridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NhcHA.png)

Comment: Where are you calling the function?

Comment: in the head section of aspx page

Comment: Any errors you have got in client-side (check dev tools)? Usually for server controls we use `ClientID` to refer ID of the control, e.g. `document.getElementById('<%= txtitemcode.ClientID %>')`.

Comment: I've made the document.getElementById('<%= txtitemcode.ClientID %>') changes now the function is working but  only the else part is executed @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: Well, try checking the comparison by adding `console.log(currentrow.cells[0].value)` before if-condition, what do you got? If the value inside it doesn't match with `checktext`, the flow will go to `else` part. The `cells[0]` content depends on what cell set as index 0.

Comment: Cannot read property 'cells' of undefined at itemvalidate in console is the error I'm facing